# CRONTAB: Cron Job Executing But Not Writing To File

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have a crontab job here to push to Github.

It works if I run my script manually but when it executes using the cron job my txt file isn't updated and nothing is pushed upstream.

I've also made sure run `sudo chmod +x /Users/myuser/Development/auto-cal/test.sh`

Not sure if I'm missing anything else - any guidance would be much appreciated!

Shell Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $((1 + $RANDOM % 100)) > main.txt

git add .

DATE=$(date)

git commit -m "$DATE"

git push -u origin main

osascript -e 'display notification "pushed to remote" with title "SUCCESS"'
```

Crontab Job:

```
* * * * * sh /Users/myuser/Development/auto-cal/test.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: is crond running?

Comment: Remove `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Do you use `sh` or `bash`?

Comment: You're trying to run a bash script with bash-specific features using `sh`. Use bash instead.

Comment: The `>/dev/null 2>&1` part hides errors and output from the script. When troubleshooting, hiding errors and output is the exact opposite of what you should be doing. Instead, *capture* errors and output with something like `>>/tmp/test-cronjob.log 2>&1`, and then examine that file for info about what's going wrong.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Start testing with a smaller script, only `echo "random" > main.txt`. You might discover that you need a path like `/tmp/main.txt`.

Comment: @illywilly : It is more than brave to throw away standard error and then trying to guess what went wrong. Don't do that. Also, I don't see any update operation in your script. BTW, is `$HOME/main.txt` being created (check its time stamp).

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting the following `test.sh`
Adding your current user login script and environments. Especially the current user PATH variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ~/.bash_profile

echo $((1 + $RANDOM % 100)) > main.txt

git add .

DATE=$(date)

git commit -m "$DATE"

git push -u origin main

osascript -e 'display notification "pushed to remote" with title "SUCCESS"'
```